# Complete and correct deductive axiom for SOL

Tags: logic

Does exist a complete, correct but no recursive deductive system for second order logic?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but can't you take something ridiculous like the system with no rules of inference and all true statements as axioms?

Comment: Bur how can we know that second order ZFC is complete and the true staments are really inambigous?? That is the answer I am looking for

Comment: @RaúlAparicioBustillo Second-order ZFC *isn't* complete, and the set of true second-order sentences really *is* "ambiguous" . . .

Answer (score 8):

Well, that depends: what do you mean by "deductive system"? (Also, what do you mean by "second-order logic"? See below . . .)

Second-order logic is **not compact**: there is a set of sentences $\Gamma$ and a sentence $\varphi$ in second-order logic, such that $\Gamma\models\varphi$ - that is, every model of $\Gamma$ is a model of $\varphi$ - but $\Gamma_0\not\models\varphi$ for any finite subset $\Gamma_0\subseteq \Gamma$. So, any (complete and correct) deductive system for second-order logic would have to allow for proofs with *infinitely many premises* - this is arguably not a deductive system anymore!

It gets worse - the set of validities in second-order logic *depends on set theory*! For example, we can write down a single second-order sentence $\varphi$ - in the empty language, no less! - such that $\varphi$ is a tautology iff $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. So even if we allow deductions to use infinitely many premises at once, we're going to have a bad day, since if $\mathcal{D}$ is a complete correct deductive system for second-order logic then (at least) one of the following must hold:

- The property "$x$ is a proof (in the sense of $\mathcal{D}$) of $\varphi$" must not be set-theoretically absolute. In particular, this means that if we want proofs to be coded by sets of natural numbers (which seems reasonable, since individual second-order sentences can be coded as individual natural numbers quite nicely), then the relation "$x$ proves $\varphi$" must be hideously complicated - it cannot be $\Sigma^1_2$, for example, and in the presence of large cardinals it has to be even worse.
- ZFC cannot prove that $\mathcal{D}$ is, in fact, a complete correct deductive system for second-order logic.

In fact, we can even show that the set of validities in second-order logic is *arbitrarily complicated*, in a precise sense: given any  model $V$ of ZFC, and any real $r\in V$, there is a forcing extension $V[G]$ such that $V[G]\models$"The set of second-order validities computes $r$."

**Basically, everything is bad forever.**

---

There's a caveat here: by "second-order logic," I assume you mean second-order logic *with the standard semantics*. We could also adopt *Henkin semantics*, at which point second-order logic is really just first-order logic in disguise, so we do have a complete, consistent, recursive deductive system. But I assume you're not doing that here.

---

EDIT: Based on your response, I suspect that you view what I've written above as evidence that second-order logic isn't really "logic" at all. You're certainly in good company, there - Quine, for instance, famously called second-order logic "set-theory in sheep's clothing". There is work on set-theoretically-absolute logics, which you may prefer; see e.g. https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/InvCriteriaLogic.pdf or http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235417283.

But my question to you, at the beginning of my answer, still stands: **what do you mean by "deductive system"**? There are logics which are not compact, but which *are* set-theoretically absolute - e.g. first-order logic together with a quantifier for "there are infinitely many $x$ such that . . ." Whether or not such a logic has a complete correct deductive system depends crucially on what you mean by "deductive system." So I think by focusing on the set-theoretic aspects of second-order logic, you're missing part of my point.

Comment: What would be some easy example of non-compactness you've mentioned? I guess it would involve second order Peano axioms, but I can't think of a working example.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, you can express "the universe is finite" as a single second-order sentence $\varphi$ (crucially, we have to use quantification over *functions* here - monadic second-order logic is nicer). So now let $\psi_n$ be the (usual first-order) sentence saying "there are at least $n$ distinct objects," and let $\Gamma=\{\psi_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$; then $\Gamma\models\varphi$ but $\Gamma_0\not\models\varphi$ for any finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$.

Comment: (To say "the universe is finite," just say there are no non-surjective self-injections: "$\forall F[\forall x, y(F(x)=F(y)\implies x=y)\implies \forall x\exists y(F(y)=x)]$.")

Comment: I think you meant for $\varphi$ to say "the universe is infinite".

Comment: @Wojowu Bah, yes, of course. :P

Answer (score 4):

As Ben Millwood wrote in a comment, the answer is trivially "yes". Take all the statements you want to be provable, and make them axioms of your new deductive system, along with no rules of inference. Then this will be a complete deductive system, in whatever sense of "complete" you used to decide on the set of statements you'd like to be provable.

More generally, if you want to capture provability with hypotheses, consider the following construction. Suppose there is some satisfaction relation $R$ whose first argument is a set of sentences $\Gamma$ and whose second argument is a sentence $\phi$. For example, $\Gamma R \phi$ might mean that $\phi$ holds in every model of $\Gamma$, or in every model of some special form (as in full second-order semantics), or $R$ could be some other relation.

Consider a deductive system in which we have only one deductive rule: "Whenever  $\Gamma R \phi$, the ordered pair $(\Gamma, \phi)$ is a deduction of $\phi$ from $\Gamma$".  Of course, this is not likely to be an effective proof system -- it allows for infinitary sets of hypotheses, and even if we limit $\Gamma$ to be finite there is no reason $R$ needs to be computable. But it does give a deductive system in which, trivially, $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ if and only if $\Gamma R \phi$.

Comment: This is exactly why one needs to define what a "deductive system" is . . . :P

Comment: Yes, of course. I had tried to write some comments below your answer, @Noah Schweber , but I couldn't find a good way to phrase them, so I decided to write this answer instead.

Comment: "For example, ΓRϕ might mean that ϕ holds in every model of Γ, or in every model of some special form (as in full second-order semantics), or RR could be some other relation." I don´t understand why full second-order semantics  "ϕ holds in every model of Γ " is an special model of "ϕ holds in every model of Γ " . They are identic!!!! – Raúl Aparicio Bustillo

Answer (score -2):

I have a problem with the term complete. I wanna mean by complete  that valid pure formulas and valid formulas of the any second order theory T we are working are true, false or undecidable independent of any set theory. If it is not the case then we can deduce the continuum hypothesis or his negation according to our "wishes" or philosophycal posture or for any independent formula that his validity  is undecidable in ZFC (or the set theory we are working). Then, the deduction that we are doing from the second order theory from axioms and inference rules of our deductive system  is not really a consequence of T, it is a consequence the set theory that we wish consider.

If this is the case, I consider that is not factible understanding "second order logic" like a real logic. Another thing it would be that any formula of language of T was valid or not valid or undecidable with this deductive system independently that we couldn´t obtain it from the deductive system because of demostration require an  infinite non recursive number of steps, in spite independent of the set theory used and their adittional axioms that we decide to add it. T. Of your answer I suppose that it is the first case the real situation. Then cardinalities of infinite sets are relative.

This situation can be not a problem for mathematical foundations, but it maybe could be a problem for experimental science, but the results of equations used to resolve problems in experimental sciences were indepent of the undecidable questions for ZFC. In the case of differential equations,statistical, Hilbert Spaces, etc... I think that results are independent of undecidable formulas in ZFC. If it wasn´t the case, the experimental science could affect to adittional axioms for ZFC.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or an extension of it? In the latter case, please edit the question to include the info, rather than posting it as a separate answer.

Comment: In any case, it is not true that formulas of second-order logic with standard semantics are true independent of set theory. Second-order logic with standard semantics is completely intertwined with set theory, in a way that which statements are true in the logic depends greatly on set-theoretic assumptions. Some have indeed argued, based on this, that second order logic with standard semantics is not really a "logic".

Comment: Sorry, not really an answer, only a question continuation. Your comment, Carl, answer my question. I understand for deductive system the inference rules and a recursive collection of logic axioms, including some methamatecally acceptable asumptions (I think independent of any sensate selection of set theory like comprehension axiom) and possibly choice axioms. Then theories in second order are more categorelly (totally in the case of PA2), but only relative a model of ZFC.