# Is it possible to derive the axiom of induction from a construction of the natural numbers?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, type-theory, meta-math, second-order-logic

If I start by constructing the natural numbers formally in a reasonably standard way...

```
Type: NaturalNumber
Constructors: zero:NaturalNumber;successor(NaturalNumber):NaturalNumber
```

...rather than axiomatising them, then it is straightforward to derive the first eight Peano axioms as theorems, in the sense that it would be relatively easy to write a verifier to do it. I asked myself then why it isn't possible to derive the ninth axiom, namely the axiom of induction?

My motivation for this is that, if you axiomatise the natural numbers rather than construct them, then as I understand it the axiom of induction is necessary in order to exclude the possibility of non-standard sets of natural numbers. Put simply, it rules out the circle of dominoes and allows only the straight line of dominoes in the following picture:

[Wikipedia: Domino effect visualizing exclusion of junk term by induction axiom.jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Domino_effect_visualizing_exclusion_of_junk_term_by_induction_axiom.jpg)

I'm aware of, although can hardly claim to be fully versed in, results such as Dedekind's, namely that with the axiom of induction stated using second order logic the Peano axioms define the natural numbers up to isomorphism. And I'm wondering whether these kinds of meta-logical arguments are needed at least to prove that such a proof as this isn't possible, perhaps?

Comment: I haven't defined precisely what my model of the natural numbers is, just thrown in some set theory and choice. I'm hoping this fuzziness will be tolerated.

Comment: Look here for proofs of the first eight Peano axioms: https://github.com/jecs-imperial/Core-Mathematics/blob/master/Peano%20axioms%20P1-P8.fls, where most of the proofs follow directly from the definitions I've given at the top of my question.

Comment: I'm sad to say that it's all a bit of a mess at the moment. I plan to pull the Peano axioms out into a separate repository soon. You can find the Intuitionistic Logic definitions in the Propositional Logic repo, which is at least in a passable state: https://github.com/jecs-imperial/Propositional-Logic

Comment: I wondered about your comment on multiplication, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: There would be nothing to prove. Given an equality, the verifier would simply unwind the terms. If you assert that $s(x)=s(y)$ then it would arrive at the assertion $x=y$. The universal quantification can safely be ignored, by the way, it is tantamount to just leaving the variables $x$ and $y$ undefined.

Comment: Incidentally, your rule is not enough to stop cycles of natural numbers. It is one half of P7 and this, in fact all the axioms P1-P8, will not stop this. Further, I am aware that P1-P8 don't rule out non-standard models. However, I have *constructed* the standard model, this is the point of the question. Perhaps you need to read my question again more carefully?

Comment: Again, I suggest you read the question more carefully and then you might stop telling someone who obviously knows that induction is needed to rule out non-standard models that very same fact! I am *constructing* the natural numbers, not *axiomatising* them. Appreciate and understand the difference and you will see the point of my question.

Comment: What does it mean to derive an axiom from a model? For instance, would you say that "$S(a)+b=a+S(b)$" is derivable from your construction since for each pair of terms $a, b$, you can rewrite the term $S(a)+b$ to get the term $a+S(b)$?

Comment: Let's say you have the construction as described at the top of my question. That is, you've defined a type and constructors that when combined give you terms. In this case $z,s(z),s(s(z))$, etc. If you want to derive P1, namely that $z$ is of type $NaturalNumber$, well, there's nothing to do, it's there in the definition of the first constructor. Similarly all the first Peano axioms P1-P8 pretty much just fall out.

Comment: I think the issue here for mathematicians is that they're not used to dealing with constructors. They tend to think that everything is axiomatised. So when you construct a model, they get confused. They also tend to think that constructors are functions, which they are not. I'm generalising here and not aiming this comment specifically at you, by the way.

Comment: Until you can rigorously define "just fall out," there isn't really a precise question here. I know you think that what you're talking about is perfectly clear, but it's really not. Again I'll ask: would you say that "$S(a)+b=a+S(b)$" is derivable from your construction since for each pair of terms $a, b$ you can rewrite the term $S(a)+b$ to get the term $a+S(b)$? "They tend to think that everything is axiomatised. So when you construct a model, they get confused." OK, teach me what I'm missing by *explaining it rigorously*.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I eschew addition and just stick to successors! If you don't, then look seven comments up to the comment starting 'There would be nothing to prove...'. This is a proof of one half of P7, namely that $s(x)=s(y)\implies x=y$. This is straightforward for you and me, and for a verifier, well, it would need to unwind the constructors on both sides of the equality $s(x)=s(y)$ in order to arrive at the equality $x=y$, and thus prove one half of the 'theorem' P7. All the other proofs follow along similar lines.

Comment: I haven't written the verifier yet, by the way. The proofs of the Peano axioms will serve as one of the first test beds for it. You can find the proofs, such as they are, here: https://github.com/jecs-imperial/Core-Mathematics/blob/master/Peano%20axioms%20P1-P8.fls

Comment: Just to labour the point, if you have a look for the proofs of P1 and P2 you will see that they are non-existent. In effect, there is nothing to prove. The assertion $zero:NaturalNumber$, for example, follows directly from the definition of the constructor, is fact it *is* precisely the definition of the constructor. So you see that these theorems really provide a useful exercise in checking the verifier and, for that matter, the type checker and grammar of the second order logic that has been implemented.

Comment: @JamesSmith: The communication problem, I think, is that for what you say "here is a construction of *Nat*", most mathematicians would say "let *Nat* be the free model of the algebraic theory with this constant and unary operation".

Comment: ... and subsequently, would take $s$ as an operation. Its action on (one way to notate the the usual construction of) the free model would be that $s$ sends $[x]$ to $[s(x)]$. (I would normally use quotes to indicate 'between here lies a string of formal symbols' but I don't recall how to format them properly in mathmode)

Comment: Sure. As I pointed out, most mathematicians simply can't grasp the concept of a constructor! Those that don't think it's a function think it's an operator...

Comment: A little more seriously though, in defining the natural numbers as an algebraic theory you are again categorising them, to use some fancy language. You may well have done enough to *uniquely characterise the natural numbers up to isomorphism* with your algebraic theories and operators and the like, but, just like Dedekind with his second order variant of the axiom of induction, you are axiomatising the natural numbers rather than constructing them.

Comment: It seems to me the only thing most mathematicians are happy to construct are sets! They are happy with the idea of an empty set, indeed they go so far as to equate it with the natural number zero! Madness! Why not just create the natural number zero? And why are mathematicians happy to accept the existence of the empty set? Because it's existence is postulated by an axiom! To effectively, and more simply, assert the existence of the empty set by defining a constructor seems anathema to them.

Comment: @JamesSmith Maybe if you *asked* one of these axiom-inclined mathematicians about this, they might respond that axiom systems have the benefit of being completely clear, in all contexts - there is no question about what it means for a theorem to follow from some axioms, since we have a completely formal proof calculus. Said hypothetical mathematician might also point out that constructors presuppose that the object being described "has enough terms" - but many theories of interest *don't* (e.g. in set theory, we usually *hope* that most objects aren't definable in any way).

Comment: Said hypothetical mathematician might also be more sympathetic to constructors if you explained what they *are*, instead of what they *aren't*, and clarified exactly how you're using them and what you're asking when you ask how to prove things using them. And finally, said hypothetical mathematician might be more positively inclined to look into the situation if you expressed honest interest in doing the same instead of hyperbole and scorn ("They are happy with the idea of an empty set, indeed they go so far as to equate it with the natural number zero! Madness!"). Just a thought.

Comment: Said hypothetical mathematician seems to lack any sense of humour. But let me address your comments...

Comment: You wrote 'constructors presuppose that the object being described "has enough terms"...'. I don't understand what you're driving at here. Can you explain? In particular, after 'e.g. in set theory...', I can't grasp what you mean here. As for constructors, I found, as a mathematician myself, that they were tricky to grasp initially, and it's difficult to put into words exactly why. I'll try to get an example in the next comment.

Comment: Suppose I write $f(x)$. You would immediately think of value of the function $f$ at $x$. In other words you would instinctively assign a *meaning* to a *term*. What constructors do is allow you no more than to *construct* that term. Ignoring types, we have a constructor $f(...)$ of arity one, that is, it takes one argument and a variable $x$, which is term in itself. So we are free to compose the term $x$ with the constructor $f(...)$ in order to arrive at the term $f(x)$.

Comment: Mathematicians tend to use variables all the time, and know pretty much precisely what they are. They also use constructors all the time, but don't realise what they are and that they are doing so, because they use terms freely without further thought. I got terribly confused when I first came across constructors because I was constantly trying to work out what they *meant*, when they don't of themselves mean anything at all.

Comment: The term $f(x)$ is just the term $f(x)$, just four characters one after the other. Annoyingly the syntax for combining constructors and variables in the intuitive way also looks like function application, but this doesn't have to be the case. $1+2$ is also just a term, equating it to the term $3$, in other words assigning it some meaning in some way, is another matter entirely.

Comment: Let me attempt a serious response! By "term" I mean term in the sense of mathematical logic - a noun, basically. So e.g. the string of symbols "$f(x)$" is a term, as is the more relevant string of symbols "$s[s[z]]$". The former has a variable, the latter doesn't terms of the latter type are *closed terms*, and the idea is that these *denote* in a meaningful way (without knowing what $x$ is, I don't know what $f(x)$ is). A term algebra is a mathematical structure whose elements are equivalence classes of terms (cont'd).

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: The equivalence relation, and the operations between the equivalence classes, are described in some appropriate way (e.g. via the appropriate constructor we can identify the terms "$s[z]+s[z]$" and "$s[s[z]]$"). A constructor is thus a very nice way to analyze/build a term algebra. However, *most structures we care about aren't term algebras*! Sometimes this is for cardinality reasons (e.g. there simply aren't enough terms for each real number to be denoted by one), but it doesn't have to be: e.g. in a countable dense linear order, no element is definable at all. (cont'd)

Comment: It's unclear what role constructors can play in such settings. By contrast, I know how to prove things about such structures, even if I can't "get my hands on them" directly, by working appropriately with axioms. E.g. the set of axioms ZFC can prove the statement "There is a unique-up-to-isomorphism countable dense linear order," and from the ZFC axioms we can prove things about this order. This is a huge degree of freedom. A less silly example, dense linear orders being pretty boring: in ZFC we can prove things about models of ZFC, even though there is no **computable** model of ZFC! (cont'd)

Comment: You write 'By "term" I mean term in the sense of mathematical logic - a noun, basically.'. Well, if we are to agree on a definition, then I would say a term as defined in second order logic, which is pretty much the language of mathematics in some loose sense, gives a good definition of a term. The Peano axioms are a good example of the use of the language of second order logic in order to do some mathematics.They have constructors of arity zero and one, and they have variables, and quantification for that matter. Some talk of the Peano axioms being *implementted* in second order logic...

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc) for the aforementioned fact. Now combine this with the fact that [there are models of ZFC where every element **is** definable](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) (!!), and this becomes a very subtle obstacle! There are natural structures which are too large (or too homogenous) to be built via a constructor; even restricting to the countable ones where every element is definable, there can be other logical barriers to them being buildable by constructors in any nice way.

Comment: It will take me a while to digest your comments in order to do them some justice and I have some work to do but I will come back to them.

Comment: @JamesSmith Great, I love second-order logic! But note that either you adopt the Henkin semantics, in which case it's just first-order logic, or you adopt the standard semantics, in which case you need a background set theory to interpret it. But this is beside the point: everything I've said applies equally well to second-order terms. There simply aren't enough of them to build most of the structures we care about. (You can improve things a bit if you allow your constructor to have undecidable equality (e.g. construct a gorup via its word problem), but the other obstacles are fundamental.)

Comment: (Actually me and second-order logic [have a bit of a love-hate relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1528324/28111), but I do love to hate it. :P)

Comment: If I vaguely see things right, without yet having taken the time to digest your comments fully, then I can well believe that it is possible to define structures the elements of which aren't definable by terms for simple cardinality reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58396/discussion-between-noah-schweber-and-james-smith).

Comment: Noah, I'm sorry to have missed your invitation for a chat. Feel free to contact me again and thank you again for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, at last, I have what I think is an acceptable answer. I'll write out the vernacular and explain as I go along.

Firstly, the construction of the natural numbers (which would be imported from elsewhere):

```
Type NaturalNumber

Constructors zero:NaturalNumber;successor(NaturalNumber):NaturalNumber
```

Next, some abbreviations and declarations:

```
Abbreviations z for zero,s for successor,Nat for NaturalNumber

Metavariables R,S,T(Nat)

Contexts ρ,σ,τ(Nat)
```

Next, the rule itself, which you would need if you wanted to prove things `by Induction`. I'll leave off the proof for a moment:

```
Rule (Induction)
  Premises
    ρ ⊢ R::P(z)
    σ ⊢ S::P(k)=>P(s(k))
  Conclusion
    τ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)
```

The first premise `ρ ⊢ R::P(z)` reads 'given a context `ρ`, the theorem `R` proves `P(z)`'. This is the propositions as types paradigm in action, if you like. The context is the axioms and proven theorems that are referenced by the theorem. Similarly for the second premise. So  we are taking as premises for the rule the base case and the induction step.  The conclusion `τ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)` states that for each natural number `n`,  a theorem `T(n)` can be constructed that proves `P(n)`, given a context `τ(n)`.

So the job is to define these contexts `τ(n)` and to construct the theorems `T(n)`. I'll give the theorems first:

```
Theorem (T(z))
  P(z)
Proof
  P(z) from T

Theorem (T(s(k)))
  P(s(k))
Proof
  P(k)=>P(s(k)) from S
  P(k) from T(k)
Therefore
  P(s(k)) by ModusPonens
```

These are worth a few comments. They would not verify standalone, so to speak, because they both rely on contexts that won't be in the main context. The verifier might return something like the following message (recall that this question is about how to implement a verifier as much as anything):

```
Theorem T(z) verified but the conclusion P(z) has not been added to the 
main context because T is not in the main context.
```

These are generic theorems that are structurally correct but do not hold standalone. It should be clear that the context needed for the first to verify fully is just going to be `ρ`. Similarly for the second theorem. The context that it needs is  going to be `σ,T(k)::P(k)`. This leads to the recursive definition of the contexts, which is the crucial bit and comes at the top of the proof that follows:

```
let τ(z)=T
let τ(s(k))=S,T(k)::P(k)
```

After the above definitions the proof of the `Induction` rule itself is broken down into the cases `n=z` and `n=s(k)`. I'll leave out the derivations which prove the implications for the moment, so as to get across the gist of the proof as a whole:

```
Proof
  ...
  n=z ∨ n=s(k)
  Suppose
    n=z
  Then
    ...
  Hence
    ρ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)
  n=z => ρ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)

  Suppose
    n=s(k)
  Then
    ...
  Hence
    ρ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)
  n=s(k) => ρ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)

Therefore 
  ρ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n) by ProofByCases
```

Now I'll write out the derivations themselves. Firstly for the case `n=z`:

```
  Suppose
    n=z
  Then
    ρ ⊢ R::P(z)
    τ(z) ⊢ R::P(z)
    τ(z) ⊢ T(z)::P(z)
  Hence
    τ(n) ⊢ T(n)::P(n)
```

In the derivation we begin by re-stating the first premise and then, since we have defined `τ(z)` to be `ρ`, the next line follows. And now note that the next line verifies. It reads 'theorem `T(z)` is a proof of `P(z)` given `τ(z)`. Well, it verifies! Because given `ρ` we can prove `R`, whatever `R` happens to be, and since our own generic theorem `T(z)` relies on nothing but `R`, the assertion `τ(z) ⊢ T(z)::P(z)` holds. And since `n` is just `z`, we are done. For the case `n=s(k)`, the reasoning is along similar lines.

**Update**: The complete proof is now [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jecs-imperial/Peano-Axioms/master/Axiom%20of%20Induction.ocs).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to prove that a "natural numbers type structure" satisfies the induction axiom. The proof will be carried out in the same set theory that is used to form the natural number type structure. The only challenge is to formalize the structure appropriately. There are many ways of specifying a "natural numbers type structure".

However, even though there are several ways to formalize inductively defined sets such as the one mentioned in the question, as long as care is taken to do it appropriately the nature of the inductive definition will ensure that the resulting structure satisfies induction. This is because, by nature, an inductive definition forms the *smallest* set possible. If the resulting set $S$ failed to satisfy the induction axiom because of some proper inductive subset, this would show that the resulting set $S$ is not actually as small as possible, leading to a contradiction.

For example, in the proof at the end of the question, we would look at the set $\{n : P(n)\}$. This would be a set that contains $0$ and is closed under successor. By the inductive definition of the construction, that set has to contain every number in the structure that was constructed - there is no need to worry about a least element or anything like that.

Comment: Carl, firstly let me write: I knew it! Let me mull over your answer, do some digging, and come back to you with questions if I may.

Comment: Some more thoughts having read through your answer again...yes, I take your point, although I don't fully understand it yet, about the 'natural numbers type structure' essentially satisfying the induction axiom.

Comment: One way I might put it is that if I extended the definition about to define a set of natural numbers, fuzzily creating what I refered to as a model, then the set would satisfy the induction axiom *a priori*. Again, I'm struggling for the words.

Comment: The reason why I asked this question is that I don't *want* to build an induction axiom into Occam, because I want Occam to be more low level than that. But I understand that if I build in the capacity to construct terms, well, essentially inductively, I might end up doing that. I wish I could find the right words! But if I could, I would probably have the full and formal answer to my own question...

Comment: A relevant link is [natural numbers type in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+type).

Comment: Okay, I think I am beginning to take your points. That's fine, you're telling me that a proof is possible, if I do the legwork and define some "natural numbers type structure". I've looked at the link in my previous comment, however, and the going is hard! Another useful link is [induction in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/induction). There the authors make the point, essentially, that the induction principle is analogous to the result that initial algebras cannot have proper subalgebras. This is close, in spirit at least, to your own comments.

Comment: The main issue with proving the induction axiom is that we need to specify which properties the structure is assumed to have, if induction is not assumed.  In set theory, the assumption might be that there is no proper inductive subset. In other contexts, induction is taken to be a rule of inference corresponding to an inductive definition.  So the main challenge is to clearly state what we do want to assume

Comment: You write: 'In other contexts, induction is taken to be a rule of inference corresponding to an inductive definition.' Exactly, yes!

Comment: In the Coq proof assistant there is an InductiveType type, and rules of inference (presumably) corresponding to that type. It is (again presumably) relatively easy (for an expert at least) to derive the induction axiom from the definition of the natural number type. I am trying to do something similar, but it is not a trivial matter to do so. The content on nLab concerned with induction and natural numbers is relevant, but it is heavy going!

Answer (score 3):

> Put simply, it rules out the circle of dominoes and allows only the straight line of dominoes...

Induction does not rule out such a circular structure on the natural numbers. In fact, induction can be shown to hold even on the set $M=\{0\}$ with $S(0)=0$. We would have:

$$\forall P\subset M:[0\in M \land \forall x\in P: S(x)\in P \implies P=M]$$

In  [Peano's axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html), it is the axiom $\forall x\in N: S(x)\ne 0$ that ensures an infinite, straight-line structure starting at $0$. Induction simply rules out the possibility of not being able to reach any particular number by repeated succession if we start at $0$.

> I asked myself then why it isn't possible to derive the ninth axiom, namely the axiom of induction.

If you want to derive Peano's Axioms including the principle of induction, you can start by assuming the existence of an arbitrary Dedekind infinite set $X$. From any such set, we can extract at least one "copy" of the set of natural numbers. For any such set, there exists $x_0\in X$ and an injective but non-surjective function $f:X\to X$ such that $\forall x\in X: f(x)\ne x_0$.

It can then be shown that there exists a subset $N\subset X$ with $x_0 \in N$ such that $(N,f,x_0)$ satisfies Peano's axioms with $f$ being the usual successor function and $x_0$ being the "first element" of set $N$.

Informally, we would have $N=\{x_0, f(x_0), f(f(x_0)\cdots \}$.

Comment: The first paragraph should be a comment rather than an answer, and the second paragraph isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: The OP seemed to be interested in somehow deriving the induction principle, but he didn't seem to quite understand its actual role. I hope my answer will be helpful in his quest.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Think of it as a hint if not a complete answer. I believe hints are seen as legitimate answers here.

Comment: I'm certainly not against hints, I just don't think this addresses the OP's question at all. I think the mistake you point out is just a superficial error which doesn't reflect real misunderstanding on their part, and your second paragraph has no actual relevance to the question; but I'll let the OP decide.

Comment: It could be that I don't fully understand the role of induction and that my assertion that it 'rules out the circle of dominoes' is something of a simplification. However, $s(z)$ does not equal $z$, it equals $s(z)$, so I don't see what your counter example proves. Finally, your link to Wolfram's page on induction provides no useful information at all as far as I can see. The second paragraph also doesn't make sense to me but to be honest, I should probably give it a more careful read.

Comment: @JamesSmith It is not a counterexample. It's an example of how induction can hold even on a finite set. I am surprised that you think the Wolfram page is not useful. It lists what I believe to be the most commonly used version of Peano's Axioms in modern textbooks. Unlike the first-order version you seem to be using, it assumes that you have set theory available.

Comment: The second paragraph states that within any Dedekind infinite set, you will find a "copy" of the set the natural numbers. So, if you want to derive the Peano's Axioms including the principle of induction, you can start by assuming the existence of an arbitrary Dedekind infinite set.

Comment: @JamesSmith See extensive edits.